# Need total kills scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a scoreboard sidebar for a map I'm making and it needs to be the total amount of zombies killed. I also want it to add 10 points for each zombie killed and display when the player presses tab. Unfortunately I know nothing about scoreboard and can't seem to find the answer anywhere else. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about scoreboards on [the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard)

---

In order to award points based on the number of kills, you'll need a Redstone Clock to check if an objective's score for a player is greater than 1, act upon it and reset that to 0.

This can be done with the scoreboard selector modifier:

```
/scoreboard players add @a[scoreboard_{Zombie Kills Objective Short Name}_min={Value}] {Dummy Objective Short Name} 10
```

Remember that to keep track of score, you need a dummy objective.

As for creating a method of tracking (objective that counts up after every) zombie kills, you can do this by measuring the 'Zombies Killed' stat.

```
/scoreboard objectives add {Short Name} stat.killEntity.Zombie {Full Display Name}
```

Comment: The syntax of the command is incorrect, it should be `/scoreboard players add @a[score_{Zombie Kills Objective Short Name}_min={Value}]  {Dummy Objective Short Name} 10` in <1.13 or `/scoreboard players add @a[scores={<Zombie Kills Objective Short Name>=<Value>}] {Dummy Objective Short Name} 10` in >= 1.13